# How to clear the label message each time when we upload a file using file uploader

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Below is my code behind code which validates whether the document that is being uploaded by the user is correct or not based on the month and year given in the textbox if the given month and year is same as in the sheet then the record gets uploaded into database else it returns that it is not a valid document.If it is not a valid document again when i upload the the sheet through file uploader then i need to hide the label msg again if not a valid document again i should display not a valid document and again while uploading  i need to clear the label message,if it is uploaded successfully again if user selects a document which is not a valid month then i should show not a valid document.Finally the requirement is to clear the label message each time when user selects the file using file uploader.How can i do this

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
 string fullpath = Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
 ReadExcelSheet obj = new ReadExcelSheet();
 //send filepath,sheet number,selected rows to class file
 DataTable dt = obj.Read(fullpath, 1);
 bool Ismatch = false;
 string getmonth = txtfromdate.Text.Trim();
 string getyear = txtToDate.Text.Trim();
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
 string date = dt.Rows[i]["Month"].ToString();
 string[] date1 = date.Split('/');
 string month = date1[0];
 string year = date1[2];
 //newly added for the existing code to obtain the month and year
 //from date
 string[] splitmonth = getmonth.Split('/');
 string newmonth = splitmonth[0].ToString();
 txtfromdate.Text = newmonth.ToString();
 //To date
 string[] splityear = getyear.Split('/');
 string newyear = splityear[2].ToString();
 txtToDate.Text = newyear.ToString();
 if (month == txtfromdate.Text && year == txtToDate.Text)
 {
 Ismatch = true;
 //break;
 }
 else
 {
 Ismatch = false;
 break;
 }
 }
 if (Ismatch == true)
 {
 lblerrorMessage.Text = "Valid Document";
 }
 else
 {
 lblerrorMessage.Text = "Not a Valid Document";
 label1.Text = "";
 return;
 }
 //checking the input month and year records exists or not in DB
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Uploaded from TestMCount ", con);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable DBdt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(DBdt);
 if (DBdt.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
 int month1;
 bool validMonth = int.TryParse(txtfromdate.Text, out month1);
 int year1;
 bool validYear = int.TryParse(txtToDate.Text, out year1);
 var filteredRows = from row in DBdt.AsEnumerable()
 let date = row.Field<System.DateTime>("Uploaded")
 where date.Month == month1 && date.Year == year1
 select row;
 DataRow[] dr = filteredRows.ToArray();
 DataTable selectedrows = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
 if (selectedrows.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i <= selectedrows.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {
 string date2 = selectedrows.Rows[i]["Uploaded"].ToString();
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("delete from TestMCount where Uploaded='" + date2 + "'", con);
 SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
 }
 SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
 objbulk.DestinationTableName = "TestMCount";
 //mapping the columns 
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "MID");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Month", "Uploaded");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Client Name", "ClientName");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Charges", "Charge");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Payment", "Payment");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Adjustment", "Adjustment");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("W/O", "WO");
 con.Open();
 objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
 con.Close();
 label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully";
 }
 else
 {
 SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
 objbulk.DestinationTableName = "TestMCount";
 //mapping the columns 
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "MID");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Month", "Uploaded");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Client Name", "ClientName");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Charges", "Charge");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Payment", "Payment");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Adjustment", "Adjustment");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("W/O", "WO");
 con.Open();
 objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
 con.Close();
 label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully";
 }
 }
 else
 {
 SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
 objbulk.DestinationTableName = "TestMCount";
 //mapping the columns 
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Month", "Uploaded");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "MID");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Client Name", "ClientName");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Charges", "Charge");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Payment", "Payment");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Adjustment", "Adjustment");
 objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("W/O", "WO");
 con.Open();
 objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
 con.Close();
 label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully";
 }
 }
 }
```

I tried the below code but the problem is it clears the label messages till the file gets uploaded once if it is uploaded again if i am giving incorrect month and year it is not showing error message that it is not a valid document

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  onchange="callme();" />

function callme() {
         document.getElementById("your message label id").value= "";
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the value of Label in javascript then,

```
function callme() {
      document.getElementById("your message label id").innerHTML= "";
}
```

Because, Label is rendered in browser as a span. Span does not have value as an attribute.

If you want to clear the value at server side, Then you need to clear at the beginning of the c# method.

```
label1.Text = string.Empty;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i had done it in the page load only by taking as lablel.text=""; in postback and without placing it in postback but it is not getting cleared because the page will not load more over I need to clear the label msg which is displayed when it is not a valid document at the time of choosing the file using file uploader

Comment: yes above is my complete code which happens when I click the button it goes into another .cs page near ReadExcelSheet obj = new ReadExcelSheet(); where the data in the sheet gets read after reading again it comes to my cs page and the next lines get executed based on the month and year given in the text boxes by the user if they are valid month and year it inserts into database else it displays not a valid document

Comment: What button do you click? When do want to clear the text of label?

Comment: after choosing the file using file uploader I will click the button where the code that I posted above is placed in that click event of that button and the message that I want to clear the label message Not a valid document each time when I upload the file using file uploader

Comment: You want to clear label1.Text right? Have you tried placing, label1.Text = string.Empty; at the beginning of that event not inside any condition?

Comment: to elaborate in clear I will specify month and year in the text boxes then I will choose file using file uploader next I will click the button then the execution starts with the above code first it checks the file name,file path and reads the sheet if the month and the year in the sheet  matches with month and year given by us then it inserts else it display not a valid document now I need to clear that  label messages each time when I selects a file using file uploader and again if the user gives incorrect month  and year again I should display not a valid doc

Comment: not label1.text I want to clear lblerrormessage.text

Comment: yes I had placed it in pageload in !postback  and out of postback also I placed it in the starting of my button click event  it is not working more over I need to clear the lblerrormessage at the time of choosing the file using fileuploader

Comment: Placing lblerrorMessage.Text = string.Empty; at the beginning of the event should work. Place a breakpoint and debug to check if the lblerrormessage.text is getting assigned after coming into the event.

Comment: yes it should work but it will work when I click the button as per your suggestion but the requirement is to clear the label message while choosing the file using file uploader only

Comment: Did you try with JavaScript?

Comment: yes I tried with javascript in this way <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  onchange="callme();" />

function callme() {
         document.getElementById("your message label id").value= "";
       }  it works fine till the uploading happens successfully but once if the sheet is uploaded if again I choose a wrong month and year that lblerror message is not displayed